# Unable to call Google's all-day events

Tags: javascript, events, google-calendar-api

I have an app that uses the Calendar v3 API call all events on Google Calendar. I'm able to call any event with a time attached to it, but no all-day events are displayed. Here is my code:

```
  get_calendar: function (name, range, callback, failcount) {
"use strict";
    if (typeof(failcount) === "undefined") {
        failcount = 0;
    }

var startMin, startMax;

// options = $.extend(this.default_opts, options);
var today = Date.today();
var time = [];

switch (range) {
case "today":
  time = [today];
  break;
case "tomorrow":
  time = [today.addDays(1)];
  break;
case "week":
  time = [today,
    today.clone().addDays(7)];
  break;
case "upcoming":
  time = [today];
  break;
default:
  // nil
}

if (time.length > 1) { // if time is more than just one day
  startMin = time[0];
  if (time[1]) {
    startMax = time[1].clone().set({hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59});
  } else {
    startMax = null;
  }
} else {
  startMin = time[0];
  startMax = time[0].clone().set({hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59});
}

var events = [];

var request = gapi.client.request({
  path: '/calendar/v3/calendars/' + name + '/events',
  params: {
    timeMin:      startMin.toISOString(),
    timeMax:      startMax.toISOString(),
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy:      'startTime'
  }
});     

request.then(function(data) {
  var entries = data.result.items;

  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    var eventEntry = entries[i];
    // var eventTitle = eventEntry.getTitle().getText();
    // console.log('Event title = ' + eventTitle);
    events.push(new Event({
      title: eventEntry.summary,
      start_time: GCal.parse_google_date(eventEntry.start.dateTime),
      end_time: GCal.parse_google_date(eventEntry.end.dateTime),
      location: eventEntry.location,
      description: eventEntry.description
    }));
  }
  // console.log(events);
  // return events;
  callback(events);
},
function() {
  if (failcount >= 3) {
    videoPlayer.queueRefresh();
  } else {
    GCal.get_calendar(name, range, callback, failcount + 1);
  }
});


 },
  parse_google_date: function(dateString) {
    return Date.parse(dateString.substring(0, 19));
  },
```

This code is then linked to:

```
                  id: "outreach",
              title: "Training & Outreach",
              size: 50,
              content: function() {GCal.get_calendar(tylerTOR, "upcoming", function(data) {
CalData.write_movies(data, "#outreach .content", "s(dddd, MMMM d\nh:mm tt)");
});}
            },
            {
              id: "events",
              size: 50,
              title: "Upcoming Events",
              content: function() {GCal.get_calendar(tylerCal, "week", function(data) {
CalData.write_ticker(data, "#events .content", "s(dddd, MMMM d\nh:mm tt) - e(h:mm tt)");
});}
            }
          ]
        } // #bottomrow
      ]
    }, // #left
    {
      id: "separator",
      size: 1,
      content: function() {$("#separator .content").html("&nbsp;")}
    },
    {
      id: "right",
      orient: "vertical",
      size: 30,
      content: [
        {
          id: "menu",
          title: "Menu",
          size: 33,
              content: function() {GCal.get_calendar(tylerMenu, "week", function(data) {
CalData.write_table(data, "#menu .content", "t()|-|d()");
});}
        },
        {
          id: "events-today",
          title: "Today @ YWAM Tyler",
          size: 33,
          content: function() {GCal.get_calendar(tylerCal, "today", function(data) {
              CalData.write_table(data, "#events-today .content", "s(h:mm) - e(h:mm tt)|-|t()")
            });
          }
        },
        {
          id: "events-tomorrow",
          title: "Tomorrow",
          size: 33, 
          content: function() {GCal.get_calendar(tylerCal, "tomorrow", function(data) {
CalData.write_table(data, "#events-tomorrow .content", "s(h:mm) - e(h:mm tt)|-|t()")
}); }
```

Any suggestions as to why all-day events are not displayed?

Comment: How did you create all-day event on your calendar? you should set start date to x and end date to x+1 day. Are you not able to create all-day events or not able to retrieve the events? please be clear on the question.

Comment: How did you create all-day event on your calendar? you should set start date to x and end date to x+1 day.  Did you try retreiving your all-day events from your calendar here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get

Comment: I'm not able to retrieve the all day events. Also, when I create an all day event it causes the code to stop working for retrieving any events. But when there are no all day events, the code retrieves the events for that day.

Comment: Can you post the request that ends up being sent (via the developer tools) and the events you expect to see in there and are not?